Maths tenure track salaries in China
I am non-Chinese and have been offered a tenure track job in mathematics in China. The offered annual salary is around 400k RMB.
The offered salary is higher than salaries I see discussed online. However, I have been told that these high salaries are a recent development of the last three years, and all the accounts I find online are older than this.
I've been told by the university that on top of this there are several grants which award research funding as well as increase one's salary. They are competitive, though some appear to have good chances of success, for example with one major provincial grant having a reported 50% success rate. Except for one national grant, no information about these grants exists online because the central government forbids disseminating information about these grants online, according to the university. If I were to be successful in most grant applications, then that would bring the annual salary to 800k which seems too good to be true.
Questions:

There are online reports of postdocs and tenure track researchers getting paid less than the promised amount, see e.g. Persistent issues with salary pay as a postdoc in China: What can I do? Is this still an issue as of the last three years?

What are usual salaries to expect in tenure track jobs in Mathematics in China?

Can this information about grants that is nowhere written down be trusted?



Is this job part of a talent program?  You may want to look into the issues with talent recruitment programs and ensure you know what you are getting into.  For US-based researchers, there is a huge amount of compliance regarding these programs.  Some US-based researchers claimed they didn't know they joined one of these programs, and they ended up in severe legal trouble.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin I've been told that the job is not part of a talent program but the additional grants I mentioned are. I am not US-based and not a US national. Anyway I didn't think about compliance and I will look into this, thanks for raising it.
